# how to use use mobile application build / zip file

Tags: php, symfony, mobile, intel-xdk

I am totally beginner in mobile frameworks. I do not understand how to use use application i build using IntelXDK?
They offer build for different mobile platforms. As a result i have dmg (for) and zip files (WebApp).

I need to upload them to remote server. 
How to make a functioning website from said files?
Actually, i also want to add Symfony2 back-end. 
Do i have to add back-end for each build separately?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that *.dmg files are programs to be run on Android.

For website build, you just have to upload zipped build and than unzip it in your server sub-directory and website will be working.